# How to post on youtube community using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, youtube, youtube-api

I know how to upload videos using youtube api and python, but I can't find smth about doing posts on a community page. Maybe you can help me with it?

I have no idea how to do it, but i hope you could help me

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to post a YouTube community post that is a text poll (I let you generalize the approach on your own).

Go on your YouTube channel `COMMUNITY` tab: https://www.youtube.com/channel/YOUR_CHANNEL_ID/community

Write a community post that is a text poll but don't click on `Post`.

Open the `Network` tab of your web-browser by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> (on Firefox) and filter XHR requests.
Now click on `Post`.

You should see a request to `create_post`, copy it as cURL (by right-clicking).
Change at your will at the end `YOUR_QUESTION`, `YOUR_OPTION_0`, `YOUR_OPTION_1`, ... and `YOUR_OPTION_N` in:

```
"commentText":"YOUR_QUESTION","pollAttachment":{"choices":["YOUR_OPTION_0","YOUR_OPTION_1", ..., "YOUR_OPTION_N"]}
```

Execute the modified cURL request in a terminal and that's it!

Note that I don't for how long this cURL request will still works.

[Source](https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API/issues/102)